# Pre requisites for a course in vibration for a Mechanical Engineering Bachelors Degree

Tags: vibration, partial-differential-equations

Can anyone please tell me what parts of **differential equations, linear and partial** I need to revise properly before I take a course in **vibrations** , in **Dynamics**,  our course in vibrations mainly deals with Free , Forced and Torsional Vibrations , so regarding Laplace transformation , Fourier series and Partial Differential Equations , **what we need to study or revise?**

Comment: This will very much depend on the curriculum.  If the course is very applied, then you probably are going to be ok with high school calculus. If you are looking at MDOF, continuous systems then you need to brush up with linear algebra apart from linear ODE's. Sometimes courses offer advice regarding the requirements.

Comment: @NMech , our course  in vibrations mainly deals with Free , Forced and Torsional Vibrations  , so regarding Laplace transformation , Fourier series and Partial Differential Equations , what we need to study or revise , please tell

Comment: Since you mention "torsional" vibrations, I would ***guess*** the most important things to revise are your courses on statics, not advanced math topics like Laplace transforms and partial differential equations. But since we don't know the curriculum or even what degree you are taking, this is just a ***guess***.

Comment: @alephzero , sorry i should have mentioned it earlier , im  in for  Mechanical Engineering Bachelors Degree , so can you please be more specific it would be better...

Comment: Also guessing, I would think a full course dedicated to dynamics of vibration needs the entire basic engineering math sequence. In particular PDE's would be central, if the course is taught with any kind of theory. Techniques for solving arbitrary PDE's are probably not necessary, but understanding where the solutions come from I think would be. If it is a typical engineering class, I'm guessing the course will describe the parametrized general solution to a handful of standard geometries, and you would adapt them to arbitrary scaling and boundary conditions per the situation

Comment: If your end goal is to practice in the practical engineering field, you might only need the basic calculus and differential equations. If you want to go beyond solving problems by applying the classic equations solved by others (usually has some limitations) and set up on your own in according to the unique conditions on hand, then you will need those advanced engineering mathematics.

Comment: Have a look in the textbook or even the suggested reading for your course. You have checked out the syllabus haven’t you?

Comment: This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.